# Duplicating column to same table in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, copy

I'm looking to rename a column in PostgreSQL with no downtime. My code will depend on the column name so I'd like to duplicate the column with a new name along with the contents and data type of the existing column, then push the code changes before deleting the original column. Is there a Postgres command for duplicating a column with its contents into the same table?

Comment: Is the table/field being updated by SQL updates at the same time as the migration will happen? If so, copying a column will lose changes when changing over since updates will happen on the old field until the code changes over.

Comment: lock table, alter table, update table setting new col to old col value, drop col.  Too bad postgres doesn't support 'MERGE'.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The field only gets updated by a cron job, so lost writes won't be an issue. The only problem is that Django will look at the models file, see that there's a missing column name, and throw up an error as soon as it starts up.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found a relatively simple way to do this in two commands:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN "new_column" <DATA TYPE STUFF FROM OLD COLUMN>;
UPDATE mytable SET new_column = old_column;
```

Didn't realise it would be this easy. I didn't lock the table as that column isn't used too frequently so a small slowdown would be okay.

Comment: Incredible solution! This comment made my day. Thanks @benwad.